# Is it possible to set timer task on a command in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Consider the following bash snippet where I'm trying to compress my file with the help of `ghostscript`

```
gs_res=$(gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="$gsoutputfile" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH "$2" 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
ec=$?
gs_error_pattern="Error:"
```

Whenever there occurs an error with ghost script process the process is not getting terminated and the rest part in the shell script is not getting executed.

It would be better if i could include the single command  line within the timer task like the following

*Not sure though,*

```
timer_task() {

gs_res=$(gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="$gsoutputfile" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH "$2" 2>&1 1>/dev/null)

}
```

And to kill the time task when the time limit exceeds. Would be a great relief if someone could help me solve this in a better way.

Comment: Gnu Coreutils has a timeout utility that'll kill the command you run with it if it doesn't complete within the allotted time.

Answer (score 0):

try using 
`set -e`
or 
    `set -o pipefail`
at the start of the script.

Comment: does this kills the entire script (or) the command which runs within the script?

Comment: set -e will stop script execution if any command fails.
set -o pipefail will let the piped commands or subshell commands to return the exit status of the first fail command or the last successful command.